# Expression Expected error when trying to add a class to an HTML Dropdown Helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm currently getting an error underneath the `@`-symbol when trying to apply some bootstrap styling to my dropdown menu in my view. The dropdown menu is created using the `Html.DropdownList` HTML helper.

The error reads:

> Expression Expected. Anonymous type member  name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments

```
Status : @Html.DropDownList("surveyStatus", "All", New With {@class = "form- control"})
```

Comment: `@class` is C#. VB would be `[class]`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. That treats the word 'class' as a variable instead of the HTML attribute Class.

Comment: Ah, I think that it should actually be `.class`.  Maybe `.[class]` but I don't think so.  I've only ever done this in C# Razor myself but a VB object initializer needs dots before each property name.

Comment: `.[class]` also doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And did `.class` work, which I said I thought should be the case? Your comment against the answer below indicates that it did.

Comment: No i'm afraid not. It solves my original error but it still changes the `.class` to an expected variable.

Comment: If it solves your original error then it DOES work, because you original error is what we were trying to solve.  If you have another error then you should post another question with all and only information relevant to the new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using C# syntax to create anonymous object. For VB.NET use

```
New With { .class = "form-control"}
```

Note, the signature of `DropDownList` method is wrong. You have to use one of the following:

- [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537935(v=vs.111).aspx)`(String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object)`
- [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548012(v=vs.111).aspx)`(String, String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object)`
- [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548204(v=vs.111).aspx)`(String, String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object, Object)`

See also [Overload List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist(v=vs.111).aspx) of the method from MSDN.

Comment: That gives me an "Overload resolution failed  because no accessible 'DropDownList' can be called without a narrowing conversion" error.

Comment: @DannyJames, that means that the issue you asked about is solved and you now have a different issue. Did you take a look at what overloads there are of that `DropDown` method? Which one are you trying to call and do the arguments you're passing make sense in that context? I don't se any overload with parameters of types `String`, `String` and `Object`.  Do you?

Comment: The overload I am using accepts a `list (of String)` (Which is retrieved from the `ViewBag` using the `surveyStatus string`), a `String` ('All') and an `Object` (Called HTMLAttributes). The `DropDown` method works fine without the HTML Attributes section of the overload. It's just when I try to add styling via an external class that I get an issue.

Comment: @DannyJames , we mean overloads of the `DropDownList` method. I append suitable signatures to my answer.

Comment: @DannyJames, you're not retrieving anything from the `ViewBag` there. You're using the literal `String` "surveyStatus". Also, what overload of `DropDownList` takes a `List(Of String)`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah i see, my apologies. I am using the second overload that you have linked. As you state this has solved my original error so I'll post another question regarding my new issues.

Comment: For the record, it was @Alexander who posted the overload links. If you're intending to use that second overload though, you probably ought to count the number of parameters it has and the number of arguments you're providing.

Comment: @DannyJames , the second overload accepts **4 arguments**, but in your code snippet 2 strings and 1 anonymous object are passed.